# What is the difference in the Code Snippets?

Tags: arrays, stride, cache-locality

I am a beginner in operating systems, and I am trying to understand some code snippets. Can you please explain to me the difference between these code snippets??

```
int sum_array_rows(int a[M][N])
 {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
      for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        sum+=a[i][j];
    return sum;
  }
```

and

```
int sum_array_col(int a[M][N])
 {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        sum+=a[i][j];
    return sum;
  }
```

The different parts are the double **For attributes** Is one of them supposed to be faster than the other?? If so can you please explain to me why, because I don't understand.

Comment: 1. your code will cause an overflow error of N and M are not equal, the lower code treat i as a column but you have used it as a row index, second on most modern operating systems there will be no difference in performance

Comment: So the first one is better than the second one ? I am sorry I don't fully understand. @SiddharthChabra

Comment: In the second one you are using `sum+=a[i][j]` when i varies from 0 toN-1 but your array is a[M][N] so your code is not correct.

Comment: What? how is this even related to operating systems?

Comment: Oh I think I get it!! Thank you very much!! @SiddharthChabra

Comment: check on "fast indices" and "slow indices".

Comment: Did you make a mistake in the second one? I suppose it shall be `sum+=a[j][i];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, the second code snippet can cause an overflow error if the array dimensions are not the same, so this issue would need to be fixed.

However looping over the last array dimension in the inner-most loop *can* be faster than otherwise, due to how the elements of multidimensional arrays are stored in memory and the caching architectures of modern CPUs.

The terms to search for here are 'cache locality' and 'stride of arrays'

Answer (score 1):

In the first example:

`i` will get the values 0, 1, 2, ..., M-1

`j` will get the values 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1

So `sum` is calculated as

```
sum = a[0][0] + a[0][1] + a[0][2] + ... + a[0][N-1] +
      a[1][0] + a[1][1] + a[1][2] + ... + a[1][N-1] +
      a[2][0] + a[2][1] + a[2][2] + ... + a[2][N-1] +
      ...
      ...
      a[M-1][0] + a[M-1][1] + a[M-1][2] + ... + a[M-1][N-1]
```

In the second example this has been switched so that

`i` will get the values 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1

`j` will get the values 0, 1, 2, ..., M-1

so now

```
sum = a[0][0] + a[0][1] + a[0][2] + ... + a[0][M-1] +
      a[1][0] + a[1][1] + a[1][2] + ... + a[1][M-1] +
      a[2][0] + a[2][1] + a[2][2] + ... + a[2][M-1] +
      ...
      ...
      a[N-1][0] + a[N-1][1] + a[N-1][2] + ... + a[N-1][M-1]
```

**Notice that the second version is wrong** because the argument is `int a[M][N]`, i.e. legal first index is `0..M-1` and legal second index is `0..N-1` In other words, if N and M differs the second version access the array out of bounds.

To make the second example correct. This line `sum+=a[i][j];` should be `sum+=a[j][i];` so that `sum` is now:

```
sum = a[0][0] + a[1][0] + a[2][0] + ... + a[M-1][0] +
      a[0][1] + a[1][1] + a[2][1] + ... + a[M-1][1] +
      a[0][2] + a[1][2] + a[2][2] + ... + a[M-1][2] +
      ...
      ...
      a[0][N-1] + a[1][N-1] + a[2][N-1] + ... + a[M-1][N-1]
```

With that change the two version are functionally identical, i.e. produce the same result. They only differ in the order that the elements are added.

Due to the memory layout of a 2D arrays and the way cache system works, the first version may perform better than the second. On the other hand, the compiler may optimize the two versions to perform equally.

Comment: I don't think that this coding error is the point of the question - it's asking about whether traversing "rows then columns" is better or worse than "column then rows".

Comment: @simon3270 You're probably right. I missed that. Too bad that OP (probably) made a typo that moved focus. Anyway, I added it to the answer

Comment: No problem - I only spotted that because I missed the M/N error!

Answer (score 0):

Both the codes works similar only if `M` and `N` values are `equal` otherwise both code blocks are different.

**Case-1 :-** Look at the below code block

```
int sum_array_rows(int a[M][N]) {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
      for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        sum+=a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

here `a` is an array of `M` rows and `N` columns & You are doing sum of each row-column element by `sum+=a[i][j]`. That's a fine code because outer loop rotates equal to number of rows and inner loop rotates equal to number of columns.

**Case-2** :- Now Look at the second code block, it causes overflow.

```
int sum_array_rows(int a[M][N]) {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        sum+=a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

Here also `a` is an  array of `M` rows and `N` columns. your first outer for loop rotate from `0` to `N` but you have only `M` rows. And when you do `sum+=a[i][..]` it creates a big problem if `M` & `N` are not same.. For e.g `M` is `2` and `N` is `5` i.e its like `int a[2][5]`  and outer loop iterates from `0` to `5` and you keep on doing

- `sum+=a[0][j]` then
- `sum+=a[1][j]` till this its fine(bcz M=2), but when it will do
- `sum+=a[2][j]` and `sum+=a[3][j]` etc then there is a problem as there is no `a[2][j]` or `a[3][j]` exits so you are trying to access out of boundary  which causes **undefined behavior**.

So Above two code blocks are same only if `M` and `N` are same, otherwise both are different.

First of all second code block is wrong, but you can correct it by doing `sum+=a[j][i]` instead of `sum+=a[i][j]` as

```
int sum_array_rows(int a[M][N]) {
    int i,j,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        sum+=a[j][i];
    return sum;
}
```

As told by others due to the memory layout of a 2D arrays and the way cache system works, the first version may perform better than the second. On the other hand, the compiler may optimize the two versions to perform equally.